# US equivalent of SCAE?

Tags: brewing-process, trade-association

Europe has the SCAE ([Specialty Coffee Association of Europe](http://www.scae.com)) which is a non-profit trade association and large community of coffee enthusiasts.  They also have established the "Coffee Diploma System" and host networking events.

In the UK, you're able to take courses towards a ["SCAE Coffee Diploma".](http://www.prufrockcoffee.com/training/the-scae-coffee-diploma/) Is there an equivalent association in the US?  I've never seen a US standard for coffee training.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a [Specialty Coffee Association of America](http://www.scaa.org/), and they have a professional development program with certificates.  (Also various awards and recognition programs.)

I'd be surprised if there was not some formal parallel in the two trade associations. The [SCAE's "about-us" page](http://www.scae.com/about-us) says: "Together with the Specialty Coffee Association of America (SCAA), we represent the speciality sector on the International Coffee Organization's Private Sector Consultative Board."

The SCAA Chronicle from Oct. 2010 carried [a story about a joint venture](http://www.scaa.org/chronicle/2010/10/07/specialty-coffee-associations-of-america-and-europe-announce-world-coffee-event-joint-venture/) with SCAE called [World Coffee Events](http://www.worldcoffeeevents.org/about-wce/), to "develop and manage competitive events on behalf of both organizations."

**Added:** There is also a [Specialty Coffee Association of Japan](http://www.scaj.org/), established in 2003.  SCAE began in 1998, and SCAA in 1982.